Does the Host Rock of This Mexican Hyalite Show Signs of Uranium Minerals? I Previously Cut It and Am Now Concerned
I previously cut a Hyalite specimen from Zacatecas, Mexico. Using a Geiger counter, I measured a slightly higher level of radioactivity on the cut surface compared to the environment. Although I know this value may not be harmful, I am concerned that it might be due to residual host rock that wasn't fully cleaned off. This has led me to worry whether the host rock of this Hyalite contains any secondary uranium minerals. I would appreciate any help in examining this.enter image description here


enter image description here



You'd probably be better of being it to a physical location to be lab tested than just giving us pictures and nonspecific numbers of ginger counts. There isn't much to be done without actual testing

However, now this specimen has been lost. I only have this picture, video, and the video of testing it. I remember testing it with a Geiger counter before I cut it. The Geiger counter showed no reaction at all. It was only because of this that I went ahead and cut the specimen.

The XKCD Radiation Dose Chart should put things in context. An hour's exposure at the value in the photo is near the smaller end of the blue chart. If you held the Geiger counter up close, then your dose from farther away will be smaller.

This feels much more like a geoscience question than a physics question - I don't think we know much about the pegmatites forming the host rock here.

I am mainly concerned about the previous cutting process and whether it will affect my environment.
